# Using map_lgl to mutate new variable

Tags: r

I created a tibble:

```
hex <- c(2,"A","L",5)

needhex <- function(n=1) { sample(hex,n, replace=TRUE)
  }

x <- tibble(hex = map(rep(10,15), needhex))
```

Accordingly, it has 15 row and 10 random characters from hex.

Now, I want to figure out a way through which I can mutate an additional column hex_two that returns true if hex row contains 2 or 5. This is what I have:

```
x %>% mutate(hex_two = map_lgl(hex,~if_else(all(. %in% c("2","5")),1,0)))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and gives this error:

```
Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a logical
```

I know there might be an easier workflow, but I am specifically looking at a way to do this using map_lgl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is a double, so instead of `map_lgl`, `map_dbl` is needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
x %>%
    mutate(hex_two = map_dbl(hex,~if_else(all(. %in% c("2","5")),1,0)))
```

---

Or if we need a logical output, we don't need the `if_else`

```
x %>%
   mutate(hex_two = map_lgl(hex, ~ all(. %in% c('2', '5'))))
```

It is also possible that the comparison should be the reverse

```
x %>%
   mutate(hex_two = map_lgl(hex, ~ all( c('2', '5') %in% .)))
```

Comment: The second function, using map_lgl, always returns false even when the row contains 2 or 5. Any reason why?

Comment: @HAK missed a `)` at the end

Comment: @HAK the reason is that you are checking in reverse, i.e. `all(c(1:5) %in% 2:3)` instead it would be `all(2:3 %in% c(1:5))`

Comment: @HAK I meant `x %>%
   mutate(hex_two = map_lgl(hex, ~ all( c('2', '5') %in% .)))`. You showed an example with no `set.seed`.  I am getting all TRUE

Comment: it seems that the function only returns true if both 2 and 5 are present. How would I alter this to check if either 2 or 5 are present?

Comment: @HAK change `all` to `any`